# Placing a bitmap into a Powerpoint Add-In

Tags: vba, bitmap, powerpoint

All:

I am writing a PowerPoint add-in that will allow a user to drop specific safety related images onto a map.  I've written the code that copies the images and places them on the slide and I would like to place it into an add-in.  Unfortunately, I cannot find a way to either:

a) place the images into the add-in

b) reference images if I were able to place them in the add-in

The alternative approach is to require the user to start with a special template that includes all of the images and then load the add-in to get the menu functionality.  I would much rather have a single file that contains both the code and bitmap images.

With best regards,

Walt

Answer (score 0):

PPA files contain only code, not presentation content like images.  As an alternative, you could distribute a PPT/PPTX that you open invisibly and extract the image you need.

Answer (score 0):

After quite a bit of looking around I found a solution that resolves the problem adequately. Using Microsoft's Custom UI Editor, I created an XML entry in the PowerPoint Presentation that performs the Auto_Open function that would have been part of the Add-In. This allows me to add the menu functions that will be responsible for loading the specific images.

I've added a reference page at the beginning of the presentation that contains instructions on how to use the template...  This page also contains all of the images that are used by the visual basic code.  The 'Visible' flag on these images are set to False so the user does not see them. As they are copied from the reference page into the presentation, the Visible flag is set to True and they are pasted onto the current slide.

It is not a perfect solution, but it is adequate...